# Como construir el llamado de username y token

Tags: oracle, webservice, aplicación-web, groovy

Tengo este curl para inicio de sesion el cual envia un username y password con el fin de generar un token , para validar el inicio de sesion me genera los valores en consola del token y del username, se esta realizando por medio de groovy, el cual me ha tocado investigar para crear otras librerias que tengo en mi codigo, me gustaria ver un ejemplo si fuese posible porfavor o intriduccion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"serv.oim.controlm","password":"UQk7#u6lEjAL4&WB"}'   "https://brux0770:8443/automation-api/session/login"
login=$(curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"${p_username}\",\"password\":\"$(cat ${p_arq_senha_auth})\"}"   "$endpoint/session/login" )
token=$(echo ${login##*token\" : \"} | cut -d '"' -f 1)


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package br.claro.controlm

import wslite.rest.RESTClient


class ControlM {
    
    def endPoint = 'https://brux0770:8443/automation-api'
    String token = 'mytoken'
    
    

    
    def fnGetAllUsers() throws Exception {
      println 'Lista usuarios configurados'
      def client = new RESTClient(endPoint)
      def response = client.get(path:'/config/authorization/users?name=*',
                             headers: [Authorization:"Bearer ${token}"],
                             requestContentType: 'application/json')
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.parsedResponseContent.text
      } else {
        return "Error"  
      }
    }
    
    def fnGetAllRoles() throws Exception {
      println 'Lista roles configurados'
      def client = new RESTClient(endPoint)
      def response = client.get(path:'/config/authorization/roles?role=*',
                             headers: [Authorization:"Bearer ${token}"],
                             requestContentType: 'application/json')
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.parsedResponseContent.text
      } else {
        return "Error"  
      }
    }
        
    
    def fnCreateUser(def name, def userLogin) throws Exception {
        try{
        def rest = new RESTClient(endPoint)
        def response = rest.post(
          path: '/config/authorization/user',
          headers: [Authorization:"Bearer ${token}"],
          body: [ Name:Matricula,    
                 FullName:NomeUser,    
                 Description:Chamado IDM :ChamadoIdm,    
                Authentication: ExternalProvider ,
                LdapUserAndDomain:LdapStringAuth] 
          requestContentType: 'application/json' )
        response.responseData
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        log.warn "Error: ${ex.message}"
      }
    }
}



try {
//    def controlM = new ControlM()
//    println(controlM.sanityStarter())
//}catch(Exception e) {
//    println("Error ${e.message}")
//}
```

Ya se saben los valores que se estan enviando, pero mi pregunta es como podria construir ese llamado con el username y el password para poder generar este token ,tengo esta clase y lo voy a colocar con demas librerias que se encargan de otras cosas,lo primordial es construir este llamado de inicio de sesion para generar ese token por medio de las variables  username y password que se envian con sus respectivos valores de la primera imagen de arriba donde señalan las flechas.

Answer (score 0):

desarrollador groovy por aquí.

Por lo que entiendo ya tienes todas tus consultas desarrolladas solo te falta que consulte el token automáticamente.

Esto debería funcionar:

```
private def endPoint= new RESTClient('https://brux0770:8443/automation-api')
private def username = 'serv.oim.controlm'
private def password = 'UQk7#u6lEjAL4&WB'

def consultaToken() {
    
    def sessionResponse = endPoint.post(path:"/session/login",query:[username:username,password:password])
    return sessionResponse.json.token
    
}
```

Asi esta funcion consultaria dicho token y podrias almacenarlo en tu variable global, pero te recomiendo que generes un token nuevo para cada peticion que realices.

Excelente Semana!

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu colaboracion